# How to see list of components to be updated when upgrading a package?

Tags: managed-package, package, isv, partner

When we are upgrading a our managed package in an org, we can see a list of components that are being updated/changed. I have noticed that we can see a list of components that are being updated by clicking on "View Components" shown at the  bottom of the page 
[image: Package Upload Page]
When we click on "View Components", we see a list of the components that have changed. The issue is that the list is much longer that it is supposed to be. So I think although we have not changed the components (e.g., classes and pages), metadata around those classes have changed, which is causing the issue.
[image]

The questions are:

1. What causes a component to show up in this list? I think it is both changes to the source code and metadata.
2. How can we minimize this list to make sure that only the components that have their source code change show up here? Because I think other changes would not have important material impact on the upgrade.

Comment: Is there any relationship between the components that are there and those that you know to be updated? It might be that the additional components have a dependency of those that are changing.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve? If you are developing the package source control should be your source of truth. If a customer it may not be relevant what is being upgraded. Even if you did have a list you cannot see what is being updated so the list would not be that useful...

Comment: I have source control as a source of truth but want to verify that with this list to reconcile and double check